# iOS Swift Networking Layer

Tags: ios, swift, networking, callback, closures

So I'm following a git repo for handling network requests. I have successfully implemented it into my application, [followed guide](https://github.com/darthpelo/NetworkLayerExample).

I'm calling the `SignInOperation` as follows in my `SignInController`: `SignInOperation(email: email, password: password).start()` So the way that this repo is setup to mainly handle the success and the failure in the RequestOperation as shown below:

```
import Foundation

public class SignInOperation: ServiceOperation {

    private let request: SignInRequest

    public var success: ((SignInItem) -> Void)?
    public var failure: ((NSError) -> Void)?

    public init(email: String, password: String, service: BackendService = MyBackendService(BackendConfiguration.shared)) {
        request = SignInRequest(email: email, password: password)
        super.init(service: service)
    }

    public override func start() {
        super.start()
        service.request(request, success: handleSuccess, failure: handleFailure)
    }

    private func handleSuccess(_ response: Any?) {
        do {
            let item = try SignInResponseMapper.process(response)
            self.success?(item)
            self.finish()
        } catch {
            handleFailure(NSError.cannotParseResponse())
        }
    }

    private func handleFailure(_ error: NSError) {
        self.failure?(error)
        self.finish()
    }
}
```

Mainly what I'm tryin to do is something like:

```
SignInOperation(email: email, password: password).start().then(
  // handleResponse
)
```

Not even necessarily like that. But just a way I can handle the response in my controller and not network file. Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated. I can DEFINITELY share more code if one feels it to be necessary.

PS. I am specifically trying to follow this design of handling your `Network Requests` because I'm building a more large scale social app. Therefor, I want something that is maintainable, scalable and testable.

Comment: You can keep the callback reference inside the SignInOperation and call when everything is done. I'd like to recommend you to use `Alamofire`. It will save your time.

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from something Like `Alamofire`. I am using `URLSession` which in return I think can provide you with the same power and ease of implementation as `Alamofire` and is not a third party dependency. However, the reason why I'm following the provided guide was because I'm trying to approach the handling of my `Network Layer` through a fully testable, scalable, and maintainable way, something I dont think you can get with `Alamofire`.

Comment: You need to look at the `PromiseKit`. I'd suggest to include it in your project. Even if you don't want to add dependency still its worth to check the implementation so that you can take the concept and write it in your own way.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the 3rd party library is not testable, scalable, and maintainable. But if you want to implement by yourself, what you need to is just keep a reference of callback closure inside your class.

Answer (score 1):

The operations success and error state is passed to closures call the closures to handle. hope below code will help you.

```
 class Test : UIViewController{

let mail = "abc@xyz.com"
let password = "******"

var operation : SignInOperation?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    operation = SignInOperation(email: mail, password: password)
    operation?.failure = { error in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        // handle failure over here
    }

    operation?.success = { item in
        // handle success here
        // you can use data from item which is an Instance of SignInItem over here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a really good answer. I'm going to wait for potential other suggestions or ideas before accepting it as the final answer. But instantiating the class object and then referencing its callback properties appears to be the correct way in handling this. Thank you for your answer.